# How to make my own generic structure to have dynamic comparator

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I want to know how i can override compareTo method in class which implements Comparable

my structure Tree is declared like this

```
public class Tree<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

and class which used that structure is Plane that looks like that

```
public class Plane implements Comparable<Plane>
```

with override compareTo method,

the thing is if i want create a tree with default comparator i can do that easily with this

```
Tree<Plane> planes = new Tree<Plane>();
```

but i want have another tree structure with planes and with different compareTo method, how i can override that method in plane?

Thanks

Comment: You can change logic of ``Tree`` -> use ``Comparator<T>`` instead of ``Comparable`` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an overloaded constructor:

```
public Tree() {
  this(Comparator.naturalOrder());
}

public Tree(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
  this.comparator = comparator; // store in a field
}
```

And then use the comparator instead of the `compareTo` method on the tree elements.

---

But note that the ability to supply a comparator removes the restriction that `T extends Comparable<T>` (which is better as `T extends Comparable<? super T>` anyway).

But in such a case, you can't have a default constructor type-safely. You would either need to require a comparator always to be passed; or provide a static factory method to create a naturally-ordered tree:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Tree<T> withNaturalOrder() {
  return new Tree<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
}
```

And invoke like

```
Tree<String> tree = Tree.withNaturalOrder();
```

Comment: thank you so much, that is exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

you could make the comparator as a parameter of Plane

```java
    public class Plane implements Comparable<Plane> {
        private Comparable<Plane> c;

        public Plane(Comparable<Plane> c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Plane another) {
            return c.compareTo(another);
        }
    }
```

whenever you want to change the compare method,just pass a diffferent Comparable instance  or a lambda expression to the constructor

Comment: thanks for reply, but then i would need for every Comparator their own planes,  they  would have same parameters, only Comparable<Plane> c  would differ. or am i wrong?